# Want a large number of Test Ethers. How to get them?

Tags: ether, testrpc, testnets, ropsten

I have made a proof of concept that works on Ropsten Test Network. Now for users to use it I need a large number of Test Ethers in my account. As far as I know, we can get only one ether with one IP in a day. I need thousands of ethers. How can I get those? Please help. Its urgent.

Comment: Do you need to run it on ropsten? You can deploy your own private testnet and there you can allocate yourself all the ether you want. If you are serious about ropsten you can rent some GPU nodes and mine ropsten yourself.

Comment: Is Rinkeby not a better option?

Comment: Can we get more ethers instantly on rinkeby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There should be no reason to need "thousands of ethers", why can't you test your script on a smaller amount? You could for testing purposes treat 1 wei as 1 ether.
2. If you would like more than 1 ether a day make use of one of these services:

   - http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/
   - https://faucet.metamask.io/

Comment: I can test it with smaller amount. But I am making it live for users to use.  So I needed a large number. I need test ether for the gas used during executing of functions in smart contract. How can I consider 1 wei as 1 ether there

Answer (score -5):

You can set the gas price to almost 0 and it'll still go through quickly on Ropsten - because Ropsten blocks are usually not filled. You may be able to simulate main net gas usage by scaling everything (incl. gas price) down by a factor of 10 or even 100. Mainnet is charging ~10Gwei for a reasonably fast transaction now. On Ropsten you can easily do with 0.1Gwei.

If you still need a few thousand Ropsten Ether, you can contact me at bitanarch@gmail.com - I can sell you some for non-test Ether.